# T test within data frame in r

Tags: r

I'd like to perform an independant t.test in a data frame

```
    eyecolor    suncream    moles
1   blue    x   10
2   blue    x   9
3   blue    x   6
4   blue    y   15
5   blue    y   7
6   blue    y   3
7   brown   x   9
8   brown   x   6
9   brown   x   4
10  brown   y   1
11  brown   y   2
12  brown   y   1
```

That means 1. selecting according to eyecolor and 2. peform t.test for nr moles in suncream x vs y.
I'm able to select with dplyr for mean, e.g.:

```
df %>% group_by(eyecolor, suncream) %>% summarize(moles.mean = mean(moles))
```

Just to make it clear, I would like to get a p-value comparing suncream x and y for every eycolor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't make it too complicated with dplyr. It is not friendly to the formula interface of t.test which is very helpfull in this particular situation. HEITZ has given an dplyr answer. Compare how the version without dplyr is not only more idiomatic but even shorter an features less nested parentheses:

```
by(df, df$eyecolor, function(subs) t.test(subs$moles ~ subs$suncream))
```

or, if you really only want to see p-values;

```
by(df, df$eyecolor, function(subs) t.test(subs$moles ~ subs$suncream)$p.value)
```

Comment: agreed. I went with dplyr because OP posted a dplyr example, so I figured it would be more familiar.

Comment: @HEITZ Agreed. I might have posted a dplyr variant, if you had not done it before me. I merely intended to add the message, that there are many ways to solve basic tasks like this as I don't think it is wise for a beginner to learn all those extra packages before learning straight R thoroughly. That is just an opinion and not meant to diminish the Advantages of the Hadleyverse world. I am more concerned about your idea, that the OP asked the question the wrong way and that ANOVA might be the more appropriate answer. You got my upvote for your first answer. Do you plan to add one with ANOVA?

Answer (score 1):

This should probably be treated in an ANOVA context. Also, the OP should take some time to digest fundamentals of null hypothesis testing and t-tests if the answer is not clear.  That said, here is an answer:

```
results = df %>% group_by(eyecolor) %>% summarize(p = t.test(moles[which(suncream == 'x')],moles[which(suncream=='y')])$p.value)
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think, that the OPs knowledge of NHST fundamentals is a problem here? That question is relevant because if this is on R syntax, the question is off topic on Cross Validated. If this is about understanding fundamentals of null hypothesis testing and t-tests it may very well be on this forum's scope.

Comment: @Bernhard: The fact that OP doesn't consider modeling the interaction via ANOVA is one clue, and the fact that OP goes straight to compute grouped means suggests (but does not necessitate) that OP fails to realize the variability between the cases is important. I may be wrong.